Unable to deploy a standalone web job via yml file
parameters:
  # Artifact Path
  artifactPath: ''
  # projects
  projects: ''
  # build configuration 'Debug' | 'Release'
  buildConfiguration: ''
  # artifact publish path
  artifactPublishPath: ''
  # Swagger file location
  swaggerFileLocation: ''
  # project dll location
  projectDllLocation: ''
  # dot net sdk version
  dotnetSDKVersion: '6.x'


steps:

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use Dot Net ${{parameters.dotnetSDKVersion}}'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: ${{parameters.dotnetSDKVersion}}
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/PDFOScanJob.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/PDFOScanJob.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/PDFOScanJob'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false


- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

#-------------- Test script to be deleted----------------------------------------------#
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Test Script '
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Testing Path......."
      write-host '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
      Get-ChildItem -Path '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*' -Recurse | Select  FullName 
#-------------- Deploy webjob----------------------------------------------#
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure Web Service Deployment'
  inputs:
      ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
      azureSubscription: '<AZ Subscription>'  
      appType: 'webApp'
      WebAppName: '<app servicename>' 
      package: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'

I am trying to deploy a web job and the pipeline seems like working, but dont see the web jobs getting popolauted in the web job balde. I see that the binaries are in the correct location of the zip file. any pointers would be agreat help.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/eoBd9.png)

Try to add your webjob folder inside App_Data folder and create 2 separate DotNetCoreCLI@2 tasks for publishing Webjob and Webapp, Refer below:-
arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/YoutubeWebJob'
Complete yaml code:-
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '**/WebJobExample.WebJob.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output/App_Data/jobs/continuous/YoutubeWebJob'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: true
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/publish_output'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'


- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'xxx subscription (01xxxxxxx7cb2a7)'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'valleywebappjob'
    packageForLinux: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    WebConfigParameters: '**/appsettings.json'

Output:-

I have also mentioned deployment of Webjob via Release pipeline, You can try the same:- azure - How to deploy a WebJob from a pipeline - Stack Overflow
